# QT QML Gridlayout desperation

Tags: qt, grid, qml

I need a fairly simple layout in qml.

I have now struggled for some time with the GridLayout, which I had actually classified as correct for this requirement - but it does not work.

This is how it should be

[image]

And this is how it is currently - the right rectangle (yellow) is completely missing.

[image]

This is my current code

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property real _encoderWidth: 254
    property real _headerHeight: 188
    property real _leftSideWidth: 70
    property real _keyboard1Height: 100
    property real _keyboard2Height: 180

    visible: true
    id: root
    objectName: "mainScreen" 
    width: 600 + _encoderWidth + _leftSideWidth 
    height: 800 + _headerHeight + _keyboard1Height + _keyboard2Height 
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
    maximumWidth: width

    GridLayout {
    id: grid
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 4
    columns: 3

        Rectangle {
            id: left
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: root.height
            Layout.maximumHeight: root.height
            Layout.minimumWidth: _leftSideWidth
            Layout.maximumWidth: _leftSideWidth
            color: "blue"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: top
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: _headerHeight
            Layout.maximumHeight: _headerHeight
            Layout.minimumWidth: root.width
            Layout.maximumWidth: root.width
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: right
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: root.height
            Layout.maximumHeight: root.height
            Layout.minimumWidth: _encoderWidth
            Layout.maximumWidth: _encoderWidth
            color: "yellow"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: content
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: 800
            Layout.maximumHeight: 800
            Layout.minimumWidth: 600
            Layout.maximumWidth: 600
            color: "green"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: bottom1
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: _keyboard1Height
            Layout.maximumHeight: _keyboard1Height
            Layout.minimumWidth: root.width
            Layout.maximumWidth: root.width
            color: "lightgray"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: bottom2
            Layout.row: 3
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.minimumHeight: _keyboard2Height
            Layout.maximumHeight: _keyboard2Height
            Layout.minimumWidth: root.width
            Layout.maximumWidth: root.width
            color: "gray"
        }
    }
}
```

The layout does not have to be dynamic, the window size is fixed and cannot be changed.

Any tip or suggestion for improvement is welcome.

Many thanks and best regards

Arne

Comment: You could use a `RowLayout` and a nested `ColumnLayout`. Then you can avoid the span properties.

Answer (score 1):

2 things I found strange in your window:

- Why use a layout if you fix all the sizes?
- Why use `root.width` for items in your middle column (except for `green`, you used 600 there)?
  It is probably that very point that pushed the yellow rectangle outside the viewport.

I'm not sure these are the proportions you are looking for.

1. I added 2 variables at the top.
2. I kept the layout even though sizes are supposed to be fixed.
3. I set the preferred sizes instead of min/max sizes.
   Note that since you do not seem to have taken the space between rectangles into consideration (`rowSpacing` and `columnSpacing`), the cost of ensuring rectangles fit in the window is that their sizes are going to be slightly different from what you expect.
4. I removed the explicitly set height for the left and right item (they are supposed to fill all 4 rows they span across.
5. I removed the explicitly set width for all but 1 item in the middle column (they are all supposed to fill the available width).

This leaves:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property real _baseWidth: 600
    property real _baseHeight: 400
    property real _encoderWidth: 254
    property real _headerHeight: 188
    property real _leftSideWidth: 70
    property real _keyboard1Height: 100
    property real _keyboard2Height: 180

    visible: true
    id: root
    objectName: "mainScreen" 
    width: _baseWidth + _encoderWidth + _leftSideWidth 
    height: _baseHeight + _headerHeight + _keyboard1Height + _keyboard2Height 
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
    maximumWidth: width

    GridLayout {
    id: grid
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 4
    columns: 3

        Rectangle {
            id: left
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: _leftSideWidth
            color: "blue"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: top
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: _headerHeight
            Layout.preferredWidth: _baseWidth
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: content
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: _baseHeight
            color: "green"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: bottom1
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: _keyboard1Height
            color: "lightgray"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: bottom2
            Layout.row: 3
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: _keyboard2Height
            color: "gray"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: right
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 4
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: _encoderWidth
            color: "yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

I let you fine-tune the thing if needed, such as including the spacing of the layout.

Comment: Hello Atmo

thanks so much for your detailed feedback and your detailed help.  The display works perfect.

I'm still pretty much at the beginning and have to familiarize myself with the whole QML topic.

I had overlooked the root.width, that should be out, sorry.

As I understand you, the layout could be made even easier because only fixed sizes are used? The alternative would be RowLayout and ColumnLayout as Peter suggested? I will test this later.

But for now I'm getting on, thanks again very much

Best regards
Arne

Comment: `RowLayout` and `ColumnLayout` are just for you to avoid having to define the `rowSpan` property. Basically, you define a 3 column layout, place rectangle 1 in first column (it will naturally expand to fill the whole window height), a row layout in the middle column with rectangles 2,4,5,6 inside it and rectangle 3 in the right column (same comment) but it will not make your window more clean or anything. The alternative I was thinking about was with the use of anchors. I do not usually recommend it but since your window or the controls inside it cannot be resized....